# Array declaration in the .h file, is it a good idea?

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-declaration

I am working in C++ and want to declare an array in the private section of the header file. Now that I am thinking about it, I thought doing so was bad practice? I would think doing this would cause multiple declarations everywhere the header is included? Almost like a mem leak?

Is this correct? I'm not sure what the standard "good" practice would be? Put all array declarations in the .cpp file?

Comment: not clear whether the array is inside a class or whether you mean a global array? The former is fine, but the latter should mostly be avoided if not for some very specific reason.

Comment: Standard 'good' practice?:- Don't use arrays.

Comment: Good point @Anders. "Private section of the header file" is ... strange..

Comment: @Konrad: Prefer `std::array` and/or `std::vector`. Seems simple enough...

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal `std::array`: OK. `std::vector`: not for static data, why should I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>(Assuming non-member, since you didn't say anything about an encapsulating type. If your use of the term "private" was to be taken literally, then please clarify your question.)</sub>

---

You won't get a memory leak; you'll get multiple definition errors.

Put all array definitions in a source file, yes, but you can "forward declare" the array with `extern` in headers.

```
// headers
extern char buf[256];

// one source file
char buf[256];
```

Not that I'd recommend the use of arrays *at all*...

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, as for using an array it's legacy code.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like `private` section of a header file. If you declare an array globally inside a header file then you may get multiple definitions (not memory leak). It's a linker error.

Best way is to declare the array as `extern` in the header file and define in the .cpp file:

```
//myfile.h
extern int a[100];

//myfile.cpp
int a[100];
```

**Note**: If you declare the array `static` or inside unnamed `namespace` inside the header file:

```
//myfile.h
static int a[100];
    OR
//myfile.h
namespace { int a[100]; }
```

then you will not get the multiple definition problem. However, a new copy of the array will be created in every `.cpp` file where the header is `#include`ed.

Comment: Using `static` for this purpose is deprecated, though. Use an unnamed namespace instead.

Comment: @Konrad, I was about to add the unnamed namespace case, but then refrained. Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I prefer and use:

```
 // Header
 extern int MyArray[];

 // CPP file
 int MyArray[] = { 1, 4, 16, 512, 8192 }; // Or give a size
```

And this works for class-level static arrays too.